# How can I refresh my jQuery Mobile styles on page resize?

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-mobile, responsive-design

I have a responsive site using jQuery mobile.

At a certain size, I swap out the header and footer (moving from a mobile like look and feel to a more traditional design) by showing the high res header and hiding the low res one.

The problem that I'm faced with is that JQM's styles don't seem to apply to the elements that are hidden, so when I adjust the screen size then the styles are all messed up.

I tried this...

```
       $(window).on('resize', function() {
           $.mobile.activePage.trigger('create');
       });
```

Which doesn't seem to do anything at all. From hunting around all the examples I've seen mention refreshing or triggering on specific elements, but I'm looking for something more page wide to allow me to use my media queries properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't do anything at all because you are calling trigger with incorrect parameter.

It should be:

```
$(window).on('resize', function() {
    $.mobile.activePage.trigger('pagecreate');
});
```

**`Create`** will only enhance page content, **`pagecreate`** will enhance page header, content and footer.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/PMrDn/52/

Comment: Thanks - that seems to be partially working for me now (I've got other problems)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
$(window).on('resize', function() 
{
    jQuery.mobile.changePage(window.location.href, 
    {
        allowSamePageTransition: true,
        transition: 'none',
        reloadPage: true
    });
 });
```

Comment: Sorry I have modified your answer by mistake.

Comment: This wouldn't work for me - I'm using a weird hybrid of jQM and Backbone, so I'm only using jQM for the front end side of things. Starting to reconsider this decision.